# Is it possible to query for the next n results after particular row?

Tags: mysql

Normally, when paginating an SQL query, we use offset and limit to select a page of rows. However, if a row is inserted or deleted before `OFFSET`, between page requests, then the request for the next page will either skip rows or duplicate previous rows.

Consider a query like

```
SELECT id FROM t
ORDER BY // a complex, dynamic order clause
OFFSET ? LIMIT ?
```

in the following scenario:

1. query with `OFFSET=0 LIMIT=1`
2. someone else deletes what was just returned as the first row
3. query for the next page with `OFFSET=1 LIMIT=1`

The row that should have been returned in #3 will actually be hidden by `OFFSET=1`.

This could all be avoided very simply if there is a way to say, "give me the next m rows after the row where id=[last row's id]" instead of "skip n rows then give me m rows". Is there an operator that does this in MySQL? Basically, I am looking for CouchDB's `startkey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  If you're sorting on three columns `ORDER BY a, b, c` and know that the last record you displayed had values `a0, b0, c0` for those columns together with PK `id0` then you can do something like this:

```
WHERE    (a, b, c, pk) > (a0, b0, c0, id0)
ORDER BY a, b, c, pk
LIMIT    m  -- don't bother with offset anymore
```

Comment: Oh man, that would totally work fine. I was avoiding that solution because I thought that the order-by clause would have to be duplicated in both client code and SQL, but that is incorrect. The client passes the order criteria and the server just creates both the order clause and the where clause at the same time.

Comment: @DanRoss: It gets a bit messy if you have some columns sorting in ascending order whilst others in descending order, as you'd then need to split apart the filter into `WHERE a > a0 OR (a = a0 AND b < b0) OR ...`—but it sounds like that's not your issue (today).